# How do I introduce an OnItemClick method to show pictures from a sql database (gridview) in a fullscreen Activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, gridview

I have a code, witch shows all the pictures from a sql database in a gridview and now i try to introduce a OnItemClick method to show this pictures in a new Activity over the full screen. I am coding in Java. Pls help me. Thanks

This is the code from thr list activity (the sqldatabase is called aood)
(there are some other things in this activity so do not wonder)

public class AoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Aood> list;
AoodAdapter adapter  = null;

GridView grid;
public static Bitmap bmp = null;
private String[]        FilePathStrings;
ImageView imageview;
private File[]          listFile;
File                    file;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aood_list_activity);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AoodAdapter(this, R.layout.aood_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM AOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        String date = cursor.getString(4);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Aood(id, name, price, image, date));                 
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

public class Aood {

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String price;
private String date;
private byte[] image;

public Aood(int id, String name, String price, byte[] image, String date) {      
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.date = date;                                             
    this.image = image;
}

public int getId() { return id; }

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDate() {return date;}

public void setDate(String date) {this.date = date;}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}
public class AoodAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Aood> aoodList;

public AoodAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Aood> aoodList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.aoodList = aoodList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return aoodList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return aoodList.get (position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice, txtDate;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup ViewGroup) {

    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgAood);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Aood aood = aoodList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(aood.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(aood.getPrice());
    holder.txtDate.setText(aood.getDate());

    byte[] aoodImage = aood.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(aoodImage, 0, aoodImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: In the adapter of your images, you need to pass an interface, add an onclick listener to your image, and register that interface in your listening class. Please provide your code for better assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you for your answers, i added the code.

Comment: @tendai I added the code, pls help me. Thanks

Comment: @tendai thank you so much... but how to show the image in a new Activity?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface that'll handle your onClick event:

```
public  interface IClickListener {
    <T> void onClick(T model);
}
```

Then change your adapter to the following, receive IClickListener in the constructor and setOnClickLister on your imageView and trigger onClick event:

```
public class AoodAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Aood> aoodList;
    private IClickListener clickListener //register clickListener to trigger onClick event

    public AoodAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Aood> aoodList, IClickListener clickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.aoodList = aoodList;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return aoodList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return aoodList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtName, txtPrice, txtDate;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup ViewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

            holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgAood);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Aood aood = aoodList.get(position);

        holder.txtName.setText(aood.getName());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(aood.getPrice());
        holder.txtDate.setText(aood.getDate());

        //setOnClickListener on imageView to trigger your interface and pass clicked object
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickListener.onClick(aood);
            }
        });

        byte[] aoodImage = aood.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(aoodImage, 0, aoodImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Then implement your interface in your Activity and override onClick as shown below:

```
public class AoodList extends AppCompatActivity implements IClickListener {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Aood> list;
    AoodAdapter adapter = null;

    GridView grid;
    public static Bitmap bmp = null;
    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    ImageView imageview;
    private File[] listFile;
    File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aood_list_activity);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AoodAdapter(this, R.layout.aood_items, list, this); //pass IClickListener
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM AOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            String date = cursor.getString(4);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Aood(id, name, price, image, date));
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    
    @Override
    public <T> void onClick(T data) {
        //then cast data onto your obj
        Aood aood = (Aood) data;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much... but how to show the image in a new Activity?

Comment: pls help me pls pls pls